# Filtering collections in java

Tags: java, collections, filtering

I am trying to filter the below cart based on payment method. 
The cart contains list of Group which in tern contains list of Items and items has list of payment methods.

Now, i want all items with payment method offered as Credit card. Is there a better way to filter it out rather than running through nested loops.

```
public class PaymentType {
    private String paymentType;
}

public class Items {
    private Integer itemId;
    private List<PaymentType> paymentOptions;
}

public class Group {
    private Integer sellerId;
    private List<Items> itemList;
}

public class Cart {
    private Integer cardId;
    private List<Group> group;
}
```

Thanks,

-Vijay

Comment: Should payment type really be a String, rather than an enum?

Comment: Payment is determined as String. The whole cart object and others are as part of complex data type in my WSDL service request.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by better.

You could maintain a HashMap which stores this information.  This avoids using loops but means you have to maintain a data structure which adds complexity and could be slower overall, depending on how you use it.

Without more information, I would take the simplest/shortest approach which is to use loops.

Comment: Actually the cart object is a complex type on my WSDL service request. I am to sort out the list and identify eligible items based on rules provided. One such rule is "All items with payment gateway Credit card". I have more rules to apply on the cart :) but the data structure the one defined.

Comment: For each type of query, you may need to add more data structures to cache the results.  Or if you use brute force, it will be simpler, perhaps slower (but perhaps more than fast enough)  You can loop through 100,000 items in a matter of milli-seconds, so looping can be an option even if performance is important.

Answer (score 0):

I would add methods to each class to find the objects you're interested in, e.g. a method `List<Item> findItemsByPaymentType(PaymentType paymentType)` to each `Group` and `Cart`. The one in `Cart` would then call the one on the `Group` class for each of its Group instances, then collecting all of the single Group results in one combined list.

This would still mean that you have to implement loops, but it would be done in a nice and clean manner in each class. Easier to test and easier to reuse.

Comment: The cart object is part of my service request and is auto generated :(

Comment: Well, that's too bad - would've been a nice chance for some real OO design. In this case, I would put the filter functionality (loops) into some kind of helper class for easier reuse. You'll thank yourself the moment you need to use it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to make PaymentType abstract with some common methods.  Then you create subclasses such as `CreditCardPayment extends PaymentType` which would enable you to do something like follows:

```
for(CreditCardPayment payment : payments)  
{  
    ccpList.add(payment);  
}
```